# How to copy data to multiple sheets from first excel sheet in a workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I want to copy cells A103 to Y148 from first sheet to every sheet in my excel workbook. What code I should use?

Comment: You will need a `For` loop going through all sheets from sheet 2 up to the last sheet and then copy the range within that loop. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. You will need to show the code you already have.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a four-step approach.
1. Design the action in plain words, like,

```
' loop through rows 103 to 148 in Sheet1
' copy the row
' loop through all other sheets in the workbook
' paste the row in the first empty row at the bottom of each
```

2. Research code for each action. For example, google for "VBA Excel loop through rows"
3. Be amazed at the multitude of ready-to-use code you will find, and at how quickly you will learn to do impossible things.
4. Come back here with any problems you can't solve on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by 'every sheet in my excel workbook', this may be faster than looping a paste operation through all of the remaining worksheets.

```
Sub galumph()
    Dim w As Long, wss As String, wsa as Variant

    For w = 2 To Worksheets.Count
        wss = wss & IIf(CBool(Len(wss)), ";", vbNullString) & Worksheets(w).Name
    Next w
    wsa = Split(wss, ";")                   'make array of worksheet names

    Worksheets(1).Range("A103:Y148").Copy   'copy from A103:Y148 on Sheet1
    Worksheets(wsa).Select                  'select all of the remaining worksheets
    Worksheets(wsa(0)).Range("A1").Activate 'activate the destination on one of the worksheets
    Worksheets(wsa(0)).Paste                'paste the data into all worksheets
End Sub
```